# NestJS TypeORM for MongoDB Crashing After Insert

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, nestjs

I’m having this weird behavior in NestJS and TypeORM for MongoDB.

When I create a new entity with `this.repo.save(newEntity);`,  the data is saved to MongoDB. But, I also get the error `cannot read property “createValueMap()” of undefined.`.

Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TypeOrm` was never created for handelling mongo and there are very trivial bugs with it but you can try creating an `ObjectID` for your schema

```
import { ObjectID } from 'mongodb'
export const toObjectId = (value: string | ObjectID): ObjectID => {
  return typeof value === 'string' ? new ObjectID(value) : value
}
```

Use this to create a new objectId also, check that the objectId should be HexaDecimal

Answer (score 18):

What solved the problem in my code was the `@ObjectIdColumn` decorator. I hope this might help someone.

```
import { BaseEntity, Column, Entity, ObjectID, ObjectIdColumn } from "typeorm";
import { TaskStatus } from "./tasks-status.enum";

@Entity()
export class Task extends BaseEntity {
    @ObjectIdColumn()
    _id: ObjectID;

    @Column()
    title: string;

    @Column()
    description: string;

    @Column()
    status: TaskStatus;
}
```

Comment: I was using a primaryColumn decorator before, and changed to this option worked for me! thanks!